# Akka.Net Streams - Source stops pulling elements when buffer throws error

Tags: .net, stream, akka-stream, akka.net

I've been playing a little with the [streams extension package](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/introduction.html) for Akka.Net and noticed this error at attempting to combine buffer and throttle methods:

```
using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("test-system"))
using (var materializer = system.Materializer(GetSettings(system)))
{
            int index = 0;
            var sink = Sink.ActorRefWithAck<KeyValue>(
                system.ActorOf<Writer>(), 
                new OnInitMessage(), 
                new OnAcknowledgeMessage(), 
                OnComplete.Instance, 
                exception => new OnError(exception));

            ServiceBusSource
                .Create(client, message =>
                {
                    var json = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValue>(json);

                    message.Complete();

                    return result;
                })
                .WithLogger(system, entity => $"{entity.Key} => {entity.Value}")
                .Buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.Fail)
                .Throttle(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 3, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
                .ToMaterialized(sink, Keep.Right)
                .Run(materializer);

            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm using [ServiceBusSource from Alpakka](https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Alpakka)
These are the packages I'm referencing:

- Akka.Streams: 1.3.1
- Akka.Streams.Azure.ServiceBus: 0.1.0
- WindowsAzure.ServiceBus: 4.1.3

I'm **intentionally** making it fail in order to see how behaves **BUT**, after failing from buffer's strategy, the stream completes and no more elements are being pulled.

**KeyValue.cs**

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime Produced { get; set; }

    public DateTime Emitted { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{Produced}] - [{Emitted}] => {Id} {Key}:{Value}";
    }
}
```

**GetSettings** Method:

```
ActorMaterializerSettings GetSettings(ActorSystem system)
        {
            return ActorMaterializerSettings.Create(system)
                .WithSupervisionStrategy(cause =>
                {
                    system.Log.Error(cause, "Failed");
                    return Directive.Resume;
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of handling errors inside of a stream - most of them described in [docs](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/error-handling.html):

1. Use `Recover` to make a fallback event from error.
2. Use `RecoverWithRetries` to allow to redirect to a different stream upon error.
3. Use `Restart.WithBackoff` to rebuild a retry stream after exponential backoff delay.
4. Use `WithSupervisionStrategy` - which is a very limited option, as it works only on stages that refer to it explicitly (as explained in docs).

Your case is by design - when you use `OverflowStrategy.Fail` it means, that once overflow is reached, an error will be produced. Reaction of most of the akka stages is to close stream immediately upon failure.

Comment: `Restart.WithBackoff` seems like the one I was looking for. Thank you