# Handling exceptions thrown when an Akka.NET Actor responds to an async request from a stream

Tags: c#, akka, actor, akka-stream, akka.net

When integrating an actor with an Akka.NET stream as described in the [Akka.NET integration docs](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/integration.html) I hit a problem with exception handling. If the actor just throws an exception then Akka swallows it, and I have to wait for the timeout to trigger for it to get reported.

I'm inferring that this is because the actor doesn't send a message back to the stream. Taking the old-school approach of using a big try-catch at a thread boundary I can marshall an exception into a message for the sender, which allows it to break through the timeout and carry on.

Example code below. As far as I can tell there's no way I can create a supervisor strategy that'll allow the stream to handle the actor's exception. What's the best pattern for handling this?

```
// Run app with argument "straightThrow" or "catchAndHandle"
class Bleurgher : ReceiveActor
{
    public Bleurgher()
    {
        Receive<string>(s => 
        {
            switch (s) {
                case "straightThrow":
                    throw new Exception("Bleurgh");
                    break;
                case "catchAndHandle":
                    try
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Bleurgh");
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Exception : {x.Message}");
                        Sender.Tell(new Akka.Actor.Status.Failure(x));
                    };
                    break;
            }

        });
    }

    public static Akka.Actor.Props Props()
    {
        return Akka.Actor.Props.Create<Bleurgher>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("cast"))
        using (var materializer = system.Materializer())
        {
            var data = new List<string>(args);

            var bleurgher = system.ActorOf(Bleurgher.Props());

            var source = Source.From(data);
            var sink = Sink.ForEach<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

            var runnable = source
                .SelectAsync(1, o => bleurgher.Ask(o, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
                .Select(o => (o.ToString()))
                .ToMaterialized(sink, Keep.Right);

            runnable.Run(materializer).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can handle failures inside stream itself. I think this answer could help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749383/akka-net-streams-source-stops-pulling-elements-when-buffer-throws-error/52886749#52886749

Comment: Yes, to some extent - perhaps I need to rephrase the question. I think those strategies will kick in once the exception is realised -- which only happens at the task timeout at the moment? I was wondering if there was a way of realising the exception as soon as it was thrown.

Comment: You can always add try/catch statement in your actor's body and return a failure message explicitly. Actors themselves don't know which messages are they supposed to respond to or not.

Comment: I haven't used Akka.NET, but am considering it. I would imagine this problem relates to unhandled exception processing by the TPL.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-and-unhandled-exceptions/

The default behaviour is for unhandled exceptions to be raised on the finalizer thread, which is not deterministic. 

Surely the Akka.NET architects understood this and provided a mechanism to surface exceptions immediately. There are lots of techniques to do this (e.g. attaching a subsequent task which executes only upon task failure and processes the exception).